Is there a way to get the JSX/TSX of a React component from the code itself?
I am writing a page to illustrate how to use a component I've developed and I'd like to build pairs of examples (rendered) with TSX source code that produces the example, ideally not having to repeat the code twice. I'd love to be able to grab the ref to the rendered component and get the TSX code from it to then inject it in a <pre> element and apply the highlighting. However the best I can seem to do is get the ìnnerHTML, which returns the component as rendered in the DOM, not the TSX code. Is there a way to achieve this? Or even better, a library that already does?

Use the react-element-to-jsx-string npm package and true Npm package and use like this:

import React from "react";
import Button from "./Button.js";
import reactElementToJSXString from "react-element-to-jsx-string";

export default function App() {
  var jsx = (
    <div className="App">
      {/*Hi*/}
      {console.log("what")}
      <h1 a={7}>test</h1>
      <h2>h2</h2>
      <Button />
    </div>
  );
  return <pre>{ reactElementToJSXString(jsx, { showFunctions: true }) }</pre>;
}


which displays to the user:
<div className="App">
  <h1 a={7}>
    test
  </h1>
  <h2>
    h2
  </h2>
  <Connect(Button) />
</div>

Actually you can just do App.toString() and i think it will work

Oh, that looks fantastic! Does it preserve the original component code or just regenerate it from the React object? E.g. will comments or such be preserved?

@Leland yes that's right

@Okarin it does preserve the component code but not everything, i updated my answer

This converts an element into a string, not a component (for instance comments or calls to hooks won’t be visible). Check my answer to get the actual code of the component, without even having to install any third-party package.

@GuillaumeBrunerie In vite, they may not be using vite, in that case mine is the best answer.

They are using Vite according to another comment. And surely all bundlers have a way to import a file as a string.

In Vite you can import a file directly as a string by adding ?raw to the import path, and then embed this string in your HTML:
import { Counter } from "./Counter";
import counterSrc from "./Counter?raw";

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Counter/>
      <pre>{counterSrc}</pre>
    </div>
  );
};

Of course you can do any kind of processing you want on that string, for instance if you want to remove imports, etc.

I suppose I could e.g. tag the beginning and end of the part to cut with comments. I used the other method for now but this would also work, thanks!

No, it's not possible to get the JSX/TSX of a React component from the code itself. This is because JSX/TSX is a syntax extension for JavaScript and it's not a part of the JavaScript runtime. When your code is transpiled, the JSX/TSX syntax is transformed into JavaScript code that creates React elements. The original JSX/TSX code is not preserved in the transpiled output.

True, but I guess I was hoping for something like a transform/middleware plugin that does this at transpilation time. It sounds like it should definitely be doable, but probably would be difficult and tied to a specific toolchain (I'm using Vite right now by the way).
